# Image blurred slightly when drawing in drawRect (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, core-graphics

I am building a circle crop function in Swift. I pretty much have everything working however when I save the cropped photo it is slightly blurry:

[image]

[image]

Not sure if it is visible here or not but on my iPhone I can see a difference, slight blurring. I'm not zooming in more than the actual size of the image. I am using a UIScrollView with max zoom factor set to 1.0. The crop code is:

```
  func didTapOk() {

    let scale = scrollView.zoomScale
    let newSize = CGSize(width: image!.size.width*scale, height: image!.size.height*scale)
    let offset = scrollView.contentOffset

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSize(width: 240, height: 240))
    let circlePath = UIBezierPath(ovalInRect: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 240, height: 240))
    circlePath.addClip()
    var sharpRect = CGRect(x: -offset.x, y: -offset.y, width: newSize.width, height: newSize.height)
    sharpRect = CGRectIntegral(sharpRect)

    image?.drawInRect(sharpRect)
    let finalImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(finalImage, nil, nil, nil)

}
```

Here I am trying to use `CGRectIntegral` to improve the result but it doesn't seem to make any difference. Any pointers on what I could do to improve this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

What's happening is your crop is blurring because it hasn't accounted for the scale of your screen (whether you're using a retina display etc).

Use `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSize(width: 240, height: 240), true, 0)` to account for the retina screen. Check [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/1623912-uigraphicsbeginimagecontextwitho) for more details on how to use this function.

Comment: Yup. This is the correct solution. (voted.) I was getting ready to post the same answer but you beat me to it.

Comment: That fixed it. Perfect now. Thanks for your help! However it appears that the outside of the circle was never transparent. Above it's actually white. After changing to the code you described it is now black. Any idea what might be going on there?

Comment: @Kex you're passing `true` into the `opaque` argument of the function. If you want transparency, you should pass `false`.

Answer (score 3):

**I suspect that, although the accepted answer above is working for you, it is only working due to the screen scale being the same as the image scale.**

As you are not rendering your image from the screen itself (you're rendering from a `UIImage` to another `UIImage`), the screen scale should be irrelevant.

You should instead be passing in the scale of the image when you create your context, like so:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSize(width: 240, height: 240), false, image.scale)
```

Comment: hey late reply here. I tried changing the scale to image.scale and the resulting image is blurred. It's fine for scale set to 0 though. Any reason for that ?

Comment: @Kex What's the size and scale of the image you're using? If the scale is lower than the screen scale - iOS will effectively upsample the image when you render it at screen scale. While this may look okay on the device itself, if you view it in an image editor (try zooming into the image) - you should see the effect of the upsampling. I'm not sure why it's not working for you with the image scale.... I just tried it myself [and got this result when zooming into the output images](https://infinit.io/_/E5UjCX6).

Answer (score 3):

Here's a way in Swift 3 to disable any interpolation.

```
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(imageSize, false, UIScreen.main.scale)    
    let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
    context?.interpolationQuality = CGInterpolationQuality.none
```

Additionally, since this is often for pixel drawing purposes, you may want to add:

```
    // Ensure the image is not drawn upside down 
    context?.saveGState()
    context?.translateBy(x: 0.0, y: maxHeight)
    context?.scaleBy(x: 1.0, y: -1.0)

    // Make the drawing
    context?.draw(yourImage, in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: maxWidth, height: maxHeight))

    // Restore the GState of the context
    context?.restoreGState()
```